# How to compile LXDE on OpenIndiana - how to deal with those AM errors in lxde-common-qt?

Tags: lxde, qt, opensolaris

Fresh install, installed ss-dev, gcc-dev, sunstudio, a few other packages I thought were relevant based on what I read. Just want to compile LXDE from source because when I look at installing from components ( http://lxde.org/download ) well not all the newer QT based stuff is there plus I get errors configuring so it's not even easier. So I use http://lxde.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb-index.cgi instead i.e. let's start with lxde-common-qt. Clone that. autogen.sh complains automake is not there. export AUTOMAKE="automake-1.10" as trying automake+tab yields that (I know this is not the best way of doing this, but using export guarantees I don't screw up in any lasting fashion). This works, as autogen goes further. Here it starts:

```
+ [ x != x ]
+ aclocal ./autogen.sh[25]: aclocal: not found [No such file or directory]
+ automake-1.10 --add-missing --copy --include-deps configure.ac: no proper invocation of AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE was found. configure.ac: You should verify that configure.ac invokes AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE, configure.ac: that aclocal.m4 is present in the top-level directory, configure.ac: and that aclocal.m4 was recently regenerated (using aclocal). configure.ac:8: installing `./install-sh' man/Makefile.am:5: ENABLE_REGENERATE_MAN does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
+ autoconf configure.ac:3: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation. configure.ac:40: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_CONDITIONAL
+ rm -rf autom4te.cache
```

---

So let's take a look at configure.ac:

```
C_PREREQ([2.57])
AC_INIT(lxde-common-qt,[0.5.5], [],lxde-common-qt)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE()
dnl  AC_PROG_INTLTOOL(, [no-xml])
dnl AM_MAINTAINER_MODE

Checks for programs. AC_PROG_INSTALL AC_PROG_LN_S

AC_ARG_ENABLE(man,
       [AC_HELP_STRING([--enable-man],
               [regenerate roff man pages from Docbook @<:@default=no@:>@])],
       [enable_man="${enableval}"],
       [enable_man=no] )  xsessions data of path for GDM AC_ARG_WITH([xsession-path],
    AS_HELP_STRING(
        [--with-xsession-path=PATH],
        [set the install path of xsession data [[DATAROOTDIR/xsessions]]]),
        [test x$withval != x && xsesspath="$withval"],
        [xsesspath="\${datarootdir}/xsessions"]) AC_SUBST(xsesspath)


if test x"$enable_man" = x"yes"; then
    AC_PATH_PROG([XSLTPROC], [xsltproc])
    if test -z "$XSLTPROC"; then
        enable_man=no
    fi

    dnl check for DocBook DTD and stylesheets in the local catalog.
    JH_CHECK_XML_CATALOG([-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.1.2//EN],
        [DocBook XML DTD V4.1.2], [], enable_man=no)
    JH_CHECK_XML_CATALOG([http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release
/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl],
        [DocBook XSL Stylesheets >= 1.70.1], [], enable_man=no) fi

AM_CONDITIONAL(ENABLE_REGENERATE_MAN, test "x$enable_man" != "xno")

AC_OUTPUT([   Makefile   startlxde-qt   lxde-logout-qt   LXDE-Qt.desktop   lxde-logout-qt.desktop   lxpanel/panel   openbox/rc.xml   man/Makefile ])

if test x"$sysconfdir" != x'/etc'; then
    echo
    echo
    echo 'Error: sysconfdir is not /etc.'
    echo 'Please consider passing --sysconfdir=/etc to configure.';
    echo 'Otherwise default config files will be installed to wrong place.'
    echo
    echo fi
```

---

Sure I see AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE is empty, so I tried putting all sorts of variations of "[lxde-common-qt 0.5.5]" but not success...

I mean no, nothing has ever been compiled on this and I don't have much experience. Usually I'll try to install missing packages, use export a bit for obvious things, but those automake errors... what is that. There's no aclocal.m4 file in the project folder:

```
AUTHORS
lxde-logout-qt.desktop.in 
autogen.shlxde-logout-qt.in
autostart
LXDE-Qt.desktop.in
ChangeLog
lxpanel config.h.in
Makefile.am configure
man configure.ac
NEWS
COPYING
openbox
desktop.conf
cmanfm-qt
imagesREADME
INSTALL
startlxde-qt.in
install-sh
wallpapers
```

Do I need to use something like a *m4_pattern_allow([^m4_cv_])* entry in the configure.ac file?

Comment: Instead of writing the answer you found yourself in an update, you should provide that part as an answer, and possible accept it. Then everyone can see this question has an acceptable answer without having to wade through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove those 2 parentheses from the AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE() line in the configure.ac file - so what remains is just AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE. After that I was able to have a configure file and install! Why it was like that in the first place will remain a mystery!

---

Well, when you have to change these by hand, it might also be that your PATH variable is not properly set, etc. so tools are not found or chained properly. Here's a sample of my new PATH, which seemingly takes care of those AM errors without having to edit the configure.ac file...:

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/SUNWspro/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/opt/onbld/bin:/opt/onbld/bin/i386:/opt/sfw/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/usr/dt/bin:/usr/openwin/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/gnu/bin/:/usr/sbin/:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/opt/onbld/bin:/opt/onbld/bin/i386:/opt/sfw/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/usr/dt/bin:/usr/openwin/bin:/usr/gnu/bin/"
```